# Sending a request for a specific ip from the dhcp

Tags: python, scapy

I want to send through Scapy discover request of certain ip address (lets say 10.0.0.30 , ( if there is such a possibility also cause the DHCP server to treat it as fixed after he give me the ip its even better )
how do I do it ?
How can I get a certain IP ?
(Of course all of the above applies on ip that right now not occupied by any client in the server (free ip right now , but no ip that never used) )

Comment: Its not a duplicate he just send discover , i want to send the discover plus sprcifick ip , so the dhcp server bring me lets say 10.0.0.2 and not 10.0.0.3 for example

Answer (score 1):

You can request a particular IP address by using the `Requested IP Address` option. Please read the [RFC][1]

In order to create such kind of request you can use the `requested_addr` option in scapy.

Here is the sample code:

```
dhcp_request = (Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/IP(src="0.0.0.0",dst="255.255.255.255")/UDP(sport=68,dport=67)/BOOTP(chaddr=hw)/DHCP(options=[("message-type","request"),("requested_addr", "10.0.0.1"),"end"]))
```

Tested on Kali linux.
[1]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132#section-9

Comment: thenk you , i will check it out

Answer (score 1):

see [dhcpig](https://github.com/tintinweb/DHCPig/blob/master/pig.py) a scapy based script that performs a DHCP exhaustion attack by sending DHCPDiscover and then DHCPRequest to ack an IP.

```
 dhcp_discover =  Ether(src=m,dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/IP(src="0.0.0.0",dst="255.255.255.255")/UDP(sport=68,dport=67)/BOOTP(chaddr=[mac2str(m)],xid=myxid)/DHCP(options=[("message-type","discover"),("hostname",hostname),"end"])
 ...
 dhcp_req = Ether(src=localm,dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/IP(src="0.0.0.0",dst="255.255.255.255")/UDP(sport=68,dport=67)/BOOTP(chaddr=[mac2str(localm)],xid=localxid)/DHCP(options=[("message-type","request"),("server_id",sip),("requested_addr",myip),("hostname",myhostname),("param_req_list","pad"),"end"])
```